# Is it correct in grammar?

Tags: present-perfect

Can we use after "When"  Present perfect tense ?

Provided that  “when” isn't in the sense of the word question, but rather that it is a synchronization device, a linking device, or something like that.

Anyway, I have an example but on the word "while."

Ex: While I've been a volunteer,we have helped a lot of young people to graduate from high school.

So can I say: We have helped a lot of young people to graduate from high school when I've been a volunteer.

Comment: You need to change your title.

Comment: _When_ doesn't seem quite right to me. _While I've been a volunteer_ obviously refers to the time of the speaker's personal experience of the organisation. Using _when_ sounds as though they are saying "We have been of help to people on the days when I was volunteering, but not at other times".

Answer (score 1):

We **have helped** a lot of young people to graduate from high school when **I've been a volunteer**. [at the time of speaking in the present]

VERSUS

We **helped** a lot of young people to graduate from high school when **I was** a volunteer. [with regard to the past time which is over.]